# Whats the difference between .equals("") and .equals(" ")?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am a newbie to selenium recently saw this piece code and was not able to understand.

```
String frnd = names.get(i).getText();
if (!frnd.trim().equals(""))
{
    System.out.println(frnd);
}
```

Whats the difference between `.equals("")` and `.equals(" ")`?

Comment: I don't see any `.equals(" ")` in your code sample. But `.equals("")` in the if conditional is checking to make sure that `frnd.trim()` is not empty.

Answer (score 3):

`.equals("")` tests if a `String` is equal to a `String` with no characters.

`.equals(" ")` tests if a `String` is equal to a `String` with one character (a space).

`frnd.trim().equals("")` tests if `frnd` consists only of white space.

Answer (score 0):

This is what it means:

- **if (!frnd.trim().equals(""))**, means that if find is NOT empty after trimming the text it should print the output.
- However, if you should use **if (!frnd.equals(" "))**  the condition is not going to be true since trim() function will delete the space and the condition will always be false (e.g. never executing **System.out.println(frnd);**).